# Using Array.prototype.filter() doesn't de-dupe array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following data I'm trying to dedupe:

**Actual**

```
var data = [
  ['dupeValue', { data: 123 }],
  ['dupeValue', { data: 123 }],
  ['otherValue', { data: 1111111 }],
  ['dupeValue', { data: 123 }]
]
```

**Expected**

```
var data = [
  ['dupeValue', { data: 123 }],
  ['otherValue', { data: 1111111 }]
]
```

I tried the following, but doesn't work:

```
data.filter((value, i, arr) => {
  return value[0] !== arr[i][0]
})
// outputs []
```

What am I missing?

```js
var data = [
  ['dupeValue', { data: 123 }],
  ['dupeValue', { data: 123 }],
  ['otherValue', { data: 1111111 }],
  ['dupeValue', { data: 123 }]
]

var result = data.filter((value, i, arr) => {
  return value[0] !== arr[i][0]
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: `arr[i]` is same as `value` so first element in each will always be equal

Comment: Are you de-duping on the sub-array value I assume.

Comment: Note that your code looks like you are only checking for the first value in the sub-array and not for the actual data. If one of the items were `["dupeValue", { data: "unique" }]`, it would get removed too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filter test is

```
var result = data.filter((value, i, arr) => {
  return value[0] !== arr[i][0]
});
```

But `arr[i]` will always refer to the current element being iterated over - the `value`, so no matter the input, `value[0] !== arr[i][0]` will always evaluate to `false`. (because `value === arr[i]`, so `value[0] === arr[i][0]`).

You might add the `value[0]` to a `Set`, and when testing, check whether that value exists in the set yet or not:

```js
var data = [
  ['dupeValue', { data: 123 }],
  ['dupeValue', { data: 123 }],
  ['otherValue', { data: 1111111 }],
  ['dupeValue', { data: 123 }]
]

const firstElements = new Set();
var result = data.filter(([firstElement]) => {
  const alreadyHas = firstElements.has(firstElement);
  firstElements.add(firstElement);
  return !alreadyHas;
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `reduce()` to map to an object and `Object.values()` to get resultant array

```js
var data = [
  ['dupeValue', { data: 123 }],
  ['dupeValue', { data: 123 }],
  ['otherValue', { data: 1111111 }],
  ['dupeValue', { data: 123 }]
]

var result = Object.values(data.reduce((a, c) => (a[c[0]] = c, a), {}))
 

console.log(result)
```